# Which Android devices support isInsideSecureHardware?

Tags: android

Does anyone know where I can find a list of devices where [`isInsideSecureHardware()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/security/keystore/KeyInfo.html#isInsideSecureHardware%28%29)
returns true? Or does it depend only on the API level?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure whether this is device specific. The documentation says:

> e.g., Trusted Execution Environment (TEE) or Secure Element (SE)

My simcard had a Secure Element to support NFC payments.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, yes the documentation is not that clear.